# How to remove empty object in which all the fields are null and those fields are removed by using " @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) "?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am using this @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) to remove null fields from the Objects. It is working as expected. Let's see with an example .

If I have an object like this -

```
User{id=null,name=null}
```

(user object which has all of its fields as null value).

In the response it is coming like ----

```
{
  user:{}
}
```

This is the thing I need to remove. Either I should assign null or remove the entire property.

Thanks for the help !.

Comment: Try `Include.NON_EMPTY` instead of `NON_NULL`.

Comment: If my answer helps request you to please accept it so that it help others as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To meet your requirement we need to use ***@JsonSerialize*** annotation with User field. Here is the working code.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Demo implements Serializable{
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomJsonSerializer.class)
    private User user;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    
    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {


    @Override
    public void serialize(User user, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (user.getId() == null && user.getName() == null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeNull();
        } else {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", user.getId());
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", user.getName());
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

if `User{id=null,name=null}`  then response will be

```
{
  "user":null
}
```

Reference - https://www.sghill.net/2012/how-do-i-write-a-jackson-json-serializer-deserializer/